# How to translate code from Ruby to Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a snippet of codes here in Ruby I would like to translate into Javascript but I'm not too familiar with the process as I'm still learning. Could anyone translate the example, it would help me greatly with my studies, thanks!

```
    class TestFunky < MiniTest::Test
  def setup
    @funky = Funky.new
  end

  def test_adds_when_you_input_a_plus_5_6_plus
    assert_equal 11, @funky.push(5).push(6).push(:+)
  end

  def test_adds_when_you_input_a_plus_6_6_plus
    assert_equal 12, @funky.push(6).push(6).push(:+)
  end
```

and another

```
class NumberArray < Array
  def sum_or_multiply(operator)
    self.inject(operator)
  end

  def push(number)
    raise TypeError unless number.is_a? (Numeric)
    super
  end
end

class Funky

  def initialize
    @numbers = NumberArray.new
  end

  def push(something)
    if operator?(something)
      process_operator(something)
    else
      store(something)
      self
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is somewhat tricky because javascript actually uses functions to define classes. There may not be any libs in javascript with `MiniTest::Test`. You can try checking out some of the stuff here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance

Comment: @locoboy Don't worry too much about that part, its custom, I just want to get an overview of the differences so I have a guideline to go from.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to evaluate here?

Comment: I think my question is not to solve it, since i didn't show the complete code(hence the snippet), but rather just wanted to be shown how Ruby codes are translated into Javascript syntax wise, if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you give something more concrete to look at? If you don't care about inheritance then you should take it out. There are certain things that don't apply to your purpose and want to make sure you get what you're looking for.

Comment: To translate between any two languages, you need to be able to write both of them. So the short answer is: learn to write Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough idea of what I think you are looking for.

These class definitions are based on the [Coffeescript implementation of classes](http://coffeescript.org/#classes) and the [Mozilla guide on Object-Oriented Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

```js
TestFunky = (function(_super) {
  function TestFunky() {
  }

  TestFunky.prototype = Object.create(_super.prototype);
  TestFunky.prototype.constructor = TestFunky;

  TestFunky.prototype.setup = function() {
    this.funky = new Funky();
  };

  TestFunky.prototype.testAddsWhenYouInputAPlus56Plus = function() {
    assert.equal(11, this.funky.push(5).push(6).push('+'));
  };

  TestFunky.prototype.testAddsWhenYouInputAPlus66Plus = function() {
    assert.equal(12, this.funky.push(6).push(6).push('+'));
  };

  return TestFunky;
})(MiniTest);

NumberArray = (function(_super) {
  function NumberArray() {
  }

  NumberArray.prototype = Object.create(_super.prototype);
  NumberArray.prototype.constructor = NumberArray;

  NumberArray.prototype.sumOrMultiply = function(operator) {
    this.inject(operator);
  };

  NumberArray.prototype.push = function(number) {
    if (typeof number !== 'number') {
      throw new Error();
    }
    _super.prototype.push.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  return NumberArray;
})(Array);

Funky = (function() {
  function Funky() {
    this.numbers = new NumberArray();
  }

  Funky.prototype.push = function(something) {
    if (this.operator(something)) {
      return this.processOperator(something);
    } else {
      this.store(something);
      return this;
    }
  };

  return Funky;
})();
```

Once these are defined, you instantiate them like this

```js
var funkyInstance = new Funky()
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that is what I'm looking for, it helps me a lot being able to see the the differences. It clarified quite a few things for me.